# Is there something like ArcGIS's Attribute Assistant available in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, update

I'd like to update attributes from an excel table based on primary/foreign key relationships.

In ArcGIS´s attribute assistant, this method exists: 
Copy Linked Records Updates an attribute of a feature with a value from a related table.

Answer (score 6):

## Read only: Join

You can add a [join](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=join#joins-menu) to the target layer. This is done in the `Vector Layer Properties` -> `Joins` dialog.

This will pull in the columns from the joined table without modifying the target dataset. If you want the columns (or derived columns) to be added to the target dataset you can use the field calculator. In this case, the join can be removed after having populated the target column(s).

## Read/Write: ExcelSync Plugin

The [plugin ExcelSync](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/excel_sync/) allows to join an existing excel file to another layer. It keeps the excel file up to date with a row for each row on the layer (1:1 relation). It also allows to configure additional columns with derived values in the excel files, which allows to add geometry-based attributes to the excel file (e.g. area, line length, WKT representation of the geometry or anything else that the infinite-in-its-versatility QGIS expression engine offers, like the possibility to pull in zip code numbers from another layer postal_code with polygons)

Comment: In other words, "no". :-) I am pondering writing a version of AA for QGIS, seems like it would be a nice challenge. I use it in the day job and really miss it when working on creating OpenStreetMap data at home. Once you've used AA, you miss it. I would NOT use VBScript expressions in my version!!

Comment: Sorry, I have never used the Attribute Assistant before, so it's hard to know its exact specs only from the question. Maybe the [shpsync plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/shpsync/) is better suited? Despite its name it's got excel specific features - and should soon be upgraded to QGIS 3.

Comment: I woke up this morning with the words "triggers and stored procedures" in my head. :-) I keep my QGIS data in PostGIS and I think that's the direction for me. With "AA", you set up a "DynamicValueTable" in your database containing rules like "when a new building polygon is created, populate its postal_code from the postal_code polygon". The rule can be an expression (in VBSCRIPT!!!) that could for example do some string processing. Full docs: https://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/

Comment: So pretty much like the shpsync plugin I think
*Links an Excel (.xls) file to a Shapefile (or any other layer). For every row on the layer a row in the Excel file is created. Derived information like area or centroid can be added to the Excel row.*

Comment: Added ExcelSync (which is the ShpSync successor for QGIS 3) to the description